# How do I select the highest priority from sql Table

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a table that assigns error priorities to error id's. But sometimes when you define an error it is possible for it to have 2 error priorities. It'll look like this in the db:

```
SELECT g.groupederrorid, f.firederrorpriority
FROM dbo.mon_tbl_groupederrorlog g, dbo.mon_tbl_firederrorlogs f 
WHERE g.groupederrorid = f.groupederrorid
WHERE applicationdbname = 'IS_APP_ELEM_STG'
AND g.errorclosed IS NULL
AND g.errordropped IS NULL
AND g.errorflowcorrected IS NULL


groupederrorid FiredErrorPriority
2411           0
3156           0
3157           0
2411           1
```

Now in ASP I've got labels that calculate the amount of high, medium etc priority errors. Of course if the errorID has two different priorities it'll be calculated in both labels. How do I prevent it from being calculated in the low priority label if it also has a medium priority assigned to it?

On the frontend it looks like this
[image]

It should not count the low priority errors if the errorID already has a higher priority assigned to it.

Here is the SQL used to get these numbers:

```
@"select count(*)
                            from dbo.mon_tbl_groupederrorlog g, dbo.mon_tbl_firederrorlogs f
                            where g.GroupedErrorID = f.GroupedErrorID
                            and ApplicationDBName = @ApplicationDBName
                            and f.firederrorpriority = '1'
                            and g.errorclosed is null
                            and g.errorDropped is null";
```

for medium priority

```
 @"select count(*)
                        from dbo.mon_tbl_groupederrorlog g, dbo.mon_tbl_firederrorlogs f
                        where g.GroupedErrorID = f.GroupedErrorID
                        and ApplicationDBName = @ApplicationDBName
                        and f.firederrorpriority = '0'
                        and g.errorclosed is null
                        and g.errorDropped is null";
```

for low priority.

Comment: which table does `applicationdbname ` belong too?

Comment: Hey Matt, the applicationDBname belongs to dbo.mon_groupederrorlog g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX` and `GROUP BY` highest

```
SELECT g.groupederrorid, MAX(f.firederrorpriority)
FROM dbo.mon_tbl_groupederrorlog g
INNER JOIN dbo.mon_tbl_firederrorlogs f ON g.groupederrorid = f.groupederrorid
WHERE applicationdbname = 'IS_APP_ELEM_STG'
AND g.errorclosed IS NULL
AND g.errordropped IS NULL
AND g.errorflowcorrected IS NULL
GROUP BY g.groupederrorid
```

Comment: This query works perfectly if I want to check for the highest error priority. But how can I count the medium error priority and the lowest? I'm sorry I'm pretty rubbish in SQL

Comment: Yea but that will still show me ID 2411 which already has a higher priority assigned to it. I've updated my question for a visual representation of my question

Comment: So only show the highest priority per id would suffice as if an id (like 2411) had two prioritys it would only show the higher id